# how to delete a specific item from table in database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to make a to-do list app, and I wanted to delete the item in the list by tapping the checkbox.

I tried to make a "deleteTask"(as you see in the code) method in the database class. Also, you can see the "populateListView"
 method, it provides data from the database into listview, I use it to refresh after each time a task got deleted from the database.

```
 public void deleteTask(String task) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL2 , new String[]{task});
    }
```

---

```
 public void populateListView() {
        try {
            mDataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            data = mDataBaseHelper.getData();
            mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (data.getCount() != 0) {
                while (data.moveToNext()) {
                    mArrayList.add(data.getString(1));
                    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_items, R.id.checkBox, mArrayList);
                    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListId);
                    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                }
                mDataBaseHelper.close();
            } else {
                toastMessage("the Database is empty");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "populateListView: error"+e.getStackTrace() );
        }
    }
```

when the application gets started, I tapped the item that I want to delete, but I see that the items start to be deleted by order from above!
one by one each time I tapped any checkbox.

Comment: The amended code doesn't even call the **`deleteTask`** method.

Comment: yes, I know! I was just trying to show the process not the final work but I did remove it know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want :-

```
public void deleteTask(String task) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL2 + "=?" , new String[]{task});
}
```

If you weren't trapping the error by using the try/catch using `db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL2 , new String[]{task});` you would get an exception along the lines of :-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  1 arguments were provided but the statement needs 0 arguments.
```

**However**

Assuming that the issue with deleting rows sequentially rather than according to the checked item(s), is likely due to the handling of the checked items. However, as the code for this is not provided it would only be guess work to know where in the code you are going wrong.

One thing is that you do not want to be creating a new listadapter instance every time you populate the ListView.

As a hint to handling a ListView, but deleting an item when it is long-clicked based upon the COL2 value, perhaps consider the following which has been based upon your code (but deletes according to long clicking an item) :-

```
public void populateLisView() {
    mDataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);  //<<<<<<<<<< NOTE 1
    list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.myListId); //<<<<<<<<<< NOTE 1
    data = mDataBaseHelper.getData(); //<<<<<<<<<< get the data to be listed

    if (listadapter == null) { //<<<<<<<<<< Only need to instantiate one adapter when it has not bee instantiated
        listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,data); // for convenience using a stock layout
        list.setAdapter(listadapter);
        //<<<<<<<<<<< add the onItemLongClick listener
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mDataBaseHelper.deleteTaskByCol2(data.get(position)); //<<<<<<<<<< gets the value of the item according to it's position in the list
                populateLisView(); //<<<<<<<<<< as the item has been deleted then refresh the Listview
                return true; // flag the event as having been handled.
            }
        });
    //<<<<<<<<<<< If the Adapter has been instantiated then refresh the ListView's data
    } else {
        listadapter.clear(); // Clear the data from the adapter
        listadapter.addAll(data); // add the new changed data to the adapter
        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // tell the adapter that the data has changed
    }
}
```

- NOTE 1

  - you would typically instantiate these variables once.
- Check the comments

You may wish to edit your question to include how you are handling the check events.

## The Full Working Example

### DatabaseHelper.java

- Note this may differ from yours a little

  public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  ```
  public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
  public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
  public static final String COL1 = "col1";
  public static final String COL2 = "col2";

  SQLiteDatabase db;

  private static final String CRT_MYTABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
          "(" +
          COL1 + " TEXT, " +
          COL2 + " TEXT" +
          ")";
  public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
      db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(CRT_MYTABLE_SQL);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

  }

  public long addMytableRow(String col1, String col2) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(COL1,col1);
      cv.put(COL2,col2);
      return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getData() {
      ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
      Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
      while (csr.moveToNext()) {
          rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL2)));
      }
      csr.close();
      return rv;
  }

  public void deleteTaskByCol2(String task) {
      db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL2 + "=?",new String[]{task});
  }
  ```

  }

### MainActivity.java

i.e. an example activity that is based upon your code, but according to the above  :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper mDataBaseHelper;
    ArrayList<String> data;
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addSomeTestData();
        populateLisView();
    }

    private void example001() {
    }

    public void populateLisView() {
        mDataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.myListId);
        data = mDataBaseHelper.getData();
        if (listadapter == null) {
            listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,data);
            list.setAdapter(listadapter);
            list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //mDataBaseHelper.deleteTaskWrong(data.get(position)); // ooops
                    mDataBaseHelper.deleteTaskByCol2(data.get(position));
                    populateLisView();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            listadapter.clear();
            listadapter.addAll(data);
            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void addSomeTestData() {
        if (mDataBaseHelper == null) {
            mDataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        }
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(),DataBaseHelper.TABLE_NAME) > 0) return;
        mDataBaseHelper.addMytableRow("Test1","Test1");
        mDataBaseHelper.addMytableRow("Test2","Test2");
        mDataBaseHelper.addMytableRow("Test3","Test3");
        mDataBaseHelper.addMytableRow("Test4","Test4");
    }
}
```

- Note AddSomeTestData adds some data for testing/demonstration.

## Result

When first run :-

[image]

After LongClicking **Test 2**

[image]

i.e. the long clicked item has been removed (from the list and the database) and the list refreshed.

Comment: can you please explain the purpose of "addSomeTestData". you did give a hint about it but I didn't get it.

Comment: Also, I am using the checkbox in the listview so I don't need to click on the item from the list to delete it. You can see above the code I just added.

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog As it says it is to add some data to test other wise the displays would be empty and there would be nothing to long-click or to delete. It is to mimic however you add data.

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog As said the above without the code that is at fault, the checkbox handling it would be pure guesswork. The above example shows **a)** how to convert the position into a value that can be used to delete a specific row and **b)** that the issue is not with the delete (when used `=?`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL2 , new String[]{task});
```

By

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL2 + " = ?" , new String[]{task});
```

Comment: actually, I was doing as you have suggested for the first time but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Ok, but you need the `` = ?``. The error is somewhere else then. If the other answer doesn't work for you either, post more code (your adapter, other parts of your activity that you think might be useful, the part where you set your click listener to delete the item, etc ..)